# How can i download a image into word document using jquery.any solution

Tags: jquery

How can i export a image into word document using jquery?

am trying like that.but only text comes.

```
$("#export").click(function(event) {
  $("#genealogy").wordExport();
});
```

Comment: Maybe look into this plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html

Comment: removed snippet. added javascript tag